# Worker pool with buffered jobs and fixed polling interval

Tags: go, worker, rate-limiting

I have a worker pool listening on a jobs channel, and responding on a results channel.

The jobs producer must run on a fixed ticker interval. Results must be flushed before reading just enough new jobs to fill up the buffer. *It's critical to flush results, and read new jobs, in batches*.

See example code below, run it on the [playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/K1h8l44MHC-).

Is it possible to rewrite this without an atomic counter for keeping track of **inflight** jobs?

```
// Worker pool with buffered jobs and fixed polling interval

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    // buf is the size of the jobs buffer
    buf := 5

    // workers is the number of workers to start
    workers := 3

    // jobs chan for workers
    jobs := make(chan int, buf)
    // results chan for workers
    results := make(chan int, buf*2)

    // jobID is incremented for each job sent on the jobs chan
    var jobID int

    // inflight is a count of the items in the jobs chan buffer
    var inflight uint64

    // pollInterval for jobs producer
    pollInterval := 500 * time.Millisecond

    // pollDone chan to stop polling
    pollDone := make(chan bool)

    // jobMultiplier on pollInterval for random job processing times
    jobMultiplier := 5

    // done chan to exit program
    done := make(chan bool)

    // Start workers
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for n := 0; n < workers; n++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go (func(n int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                // Receive from channel or block
                jobID, more := <-jobs
                if more {
                    // To subtract a signed positive constant value...
                    // https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddUint64
                    c := atomic.AddUint64(&inflight, ^uint64(0))
                    fmt.Println(
                        fmt.Sprintf("worker %v processing %v - %v jobs left",
                            n, jobID, c))
                    // Processing the job...
                    m := rand.Intn(jobMultiplier)
                    time.Sleep(time.Duration(m) * pollInterval)
                    results <- jobID
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("worker %v exited", n))
                    return
                }
            }
        })(n)
    }

    // Signal to exit
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sig, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    fmt.Println("ctrl+c to exit")

    go (func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(pollInterval)
        r := make([]string, 0)
        flushResults := func() {
            fmt.Println(
                fmt.Sprintf("===> results: %v", strings.Join(r, ",")))
            r = make([]string, 0)
        }

        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                flushResults()

                // Fetch jobs
                c := atomic.LoadUint64(&inflight)
                d := uint64(buf) - c
                for i := 0; i < int(d); i++ {
                    jobID++
                    jobs <- jobID
                    atomic.AddUint64(&inflight, 1)
                }
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("===> send %v jobs", d))

            case jobID := <-results:
                r = append(r, fmt.Sprintf("%v", jobID))

            case <-pollDone:
                // Stop polling for new jobs
                ticker.Stop()

                // Close jobs channel to stop workers
                close(jobs)

                // Wait for workers to exit
                wg.Wait()
                close(results)

                // Flush remaining results
                for {
                    jobID, more := <-results
                    if more {
                        r = append(r, fmt.Sprintf("%v", jobID))
                    } else {
                        break
                    }
                }
                flushResults()

                // Done!
                done <- true
                return
            }
        }
    })()

    // Wait for exit signal
    <-sig

    fmt.Println("---------| EXIT |---------")
    pollDone <- true
    <-done
    fmt.Println("...done")
}
```

Comment: Re-writing this for you is likely too broad for an SO answer, but you cannot use atomics for this type of things. Atomic operations provide no synchronization, only safe memory access. For example, by the time you print `%v jobs left` it's probably incorrect; and the iteration of the `inflight` number is also going to run into the same problem where the value is stale as soon as you read it.

Comment: Also, you should never use unsigned values for cardinals. When two workers hit the last "fetch jobs" at the same time you are going to have `18446744073709551615` jobs left and then try to load 6 jobs into a buffer of 5.

Comment: Could you send batches over the channel, instead of sending individual jobs?

Comment: @Adrian possibly, but I would like to define the worker as having to deal with a single job only. In my use case the job can already be a batch of similar tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a channel-based version of your code, functionally equivalent to the intent of the example above. The key points is that we're not using any atomic values to vary the logic of the code, because that offers no synchronization between the goroutines. All interactions between the goroutines are synchronized using channels, `sync.WaitGroup`, or `context.Context`. There are probably better ways to solve the problem at hand, but this demonstrates that there are no atomics necessary to coordinate the queue and workers.

The only value that is still left uncoordinated between goroutines here is the use of `len(jobs)` in the log output. Whether it makes sense to use it or not is up to you, as its value is meaningless in a concurrent world, but it's *safe* because it's synchronized for concurrent use and there is no logic based on the value.

```
buf := 5
workers := 3
jobs := make(chan int, buf)

// results buffer must always be larger than workers + buf to prevent deadlock
results := make(chan int, buf*2)

ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

// Start workers
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for n := 0; n < workers; n++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(n int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for jobID := range jobs {
            fmt.Printf("worker %v processing %v - %v jobs left\n", n, jobID, len(jobs))
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(5)) * pollInterval)
            results <- jobID
        }
        fmt.Printf("worker %v exited", n)
    }(n)
}

var done sync.WaitGroup
done.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer done.Done()
    ticker := time.NewTicker(pollInterval)
    r := make([]string, 0)

    flushResults := func() {
        fmt.Printf("===> results: %v\n", strings.Join(r, ","))
        r = r[:0]
    }

    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            flushResults()

            // send max buf jobs, or fill the queue
            for i := 0; i < buf; i++ {
                jobID++
                select {
                case jobs <- jobID:
                    continue
                }
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf("===> send %v jobs\n", i)

        case jobID := <-results:
            r = append(r, fmt.Sprintf("%v", jobID))

        case <-ctx.Done():
            // Close jobs channel to stop workers
            close(jobs)
            // Wait for workers to exit
            wg.Wait()

            // we can close results for easy iteration because we know
            // there are no more workers.
            close(results)
            // Flush remaining results
            for jobID := range results {
                r = append(r, fmt.Sprintf("%v", jobID))
            }
            flushResults()
            return
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: Combining the for and select statements didn't occur to me, and I wasn't aware of the label syntax, simple solution. Thanks for answering! Having an inflight number to report on might be useful, and len(jobs) is good enough, the atomic counter is not needed. Noted about both of them being stale as soon as you've read them. Playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/MD9su-_NUxZ

Comment: for+select is such a common pattern, that users have proposed that it even be given special syntax. I don't particularly like labels, but `break` being used for select requires a little awkwardness -- you'll often see an anonymous function used so that you can `return` rather than use a labeled `break`.

Comment: Special syntax for for+select makes sense. I specifically meant the `for select break` on BATCH. In my originally post the intention was to do something like `jobIDs = stream.read(d)`. Now I'll do `i < buf; i += x... jobIDs = stream.read(x)` items at a time